# $state resolve ignores ID

Tags: angularjs

I have this state to go to the User Profile Edit Form:

```
  //state for edit User Profile
  .state('users.edit', {
    url: '/users/{id}/edit',
    templateUrl: 'users/user-edit.html',
    controller: 'UserEditCtrl',
    resolve: {
      user: ['$stateParams', 'users', function($stateParams, users) {
        return users.get($stateParams.id);
      }]
    }
  });
```

The Edit Profile Button sends the right ID:

```
ng-href="#/users/{{user.id}}/edit"
```

When I click on it it goes to #/users/1/edit, so no problem here.

The GET model:

```
angular.module('bidrp')
.factory('users', [
'$http',

function($http){
  var o = {
    users: [{email:"user@email.com"}]
  };
  o.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/users/' + id + '.json').then(function(res){
      return res.data;
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);
```

When I click on the Edit Profile Button, it sends a get request to /users/edit.json and I of course get an error 500. It should be sending a GET request to /users/1.json instead ...

**Why does Angular think that "edit" is my ID and not {id} ?**

Comment: DId you try the route as ` url: '/users/:id/edit',` i am not so sure about `{id}`

Comment: yes tried that already, results in the same story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using ui-router.

The route is usually with `:id` but works even with `{id}`.

Second point is when you navigate you shouldn't use `ng-href` but `ui-sref` like: `<a ui-sref="users.edit({id: user.id })">...`

I created for you working solution with your code (open the network tab in console too see resolve of your users factory)
http://plnkr.co/edit/pseDp460zJb2Na4AgjSh?p=preview
(when you comment 38 line in script.js you will have "working app")